# Django NoReverseMatch Exception for regular expression matching 2 routes

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

```
url(r'^v1/(statistics|analytics)/stats_bar$', views.stats_bar, name='stats_bar')

reverse('stats_bar')
```

**Throws**: *Reverse for 'stats_bar' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['v1/(statistics|analytics)/stats_bar$']*

Is there any way to manipulate the pattern Django tries or another simple way to deal with this issue?

Django==1.6.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think django is interpreting `(statics|analytics)` as a pattern for variable. I suggest as follow:

1. define 2 different url to the same view:

   ```
   url(r'^v1/statistics/stats_bar$', views.stats_bar, name='stats_bar_statistics')
   url(r'^v1/analytics/stats_bar$', views.stats_bar, name='stats_bar_analytics')

   reverse('status_bar_statistics') # usage
   ```

   and inside the view test which url has been used:

   ```
   if 'analytics' in request.path:
       # do something
   elif 'statistics' in request.path:
       # do otherthing
   ```
2. you define one url with parameter:

   ```
   url(r'^v1/ (?P<type>(statistics|analytics))/stats_bar$', views.stats_bar, name='stats_bar')

   reverse('status_bar', kwargs={'type': 'statistics'}) # usage
   ```

Comment: @knbk did you test it? I already test this and it works good for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the relevant code in django. It is not supported, except for in capturing groups, in which case it is just completely replaced by the appropriate parameter. That means your solution is entirely valid.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Look at the section about args.